Destructor defined through a type alias
This code
struct Inner{
    Inner();
    ~Inner();
};

struct Outer {
    using Inner = ::Inner;
};

Outer::Inner::Inner()
{
    //
}

Outer::Inner::~Inner()
{
    //
}

is compiled by GCC up to the latest as of today (14.2) but is rejected by clang since version 11 (accepted by clang 10).
It's strange (to me) that only the destructor is rejected.
Which compiler is right? Can somebody cite chapter and verse from the standard?

Out of curiosity: since Inner is atually a separate struct, why didn't you define its ctor and dtor simply Inner::Inner() {...}, Inner::~Inner() {...} ?

If you change the code to using Inn = ::Inner;, then Outer::Inn::Inner(){} and Outer::Inn::~Inner(){} compiles fine on both compilers. Why? I don't know.

I can not see anything in the latest C++ standard that would forbid to define a destructor via alias.
Here clang patch that actually implements this diagnostic. The reason why it was implemented is still unknown to me https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20200210/305859.html

@wohlstad I didn't write this code, a cow orker did. They must have really liked the scope resolution operator. It would never occur to me to write such a thing.

Can typedef names be used to declare or define constructors?

@user12002570 I'd say this question is more about why in the constructor declaration, the lookup for the last Inner finds injected-class-name, but in the destructor declaration — the type alias

In my mind this is really convoluted code. Why are we defining an aliased object through that alias? That doesn't make sense. Define Inner as it is — without Outer. Then if you wish to alias it elsewhere do it, but use it as such — an alias for another type. No need to define/redefine the thing in terms of some other thing. That just makes a maddening code perusal and a maintenance nightmare.

Per C++23 DIS [basic.lookup.qual.general]/41:

If a qualified name Q follows a ~:
… its nested-name-specifier N shall nominate a type.
If N has another nested-name-specifier S, Q is looked up as if its lookup context were that nominated by S.

Inner after ~ in Outer::Inner::~Inner is looked up in Outer, which finds type alias. But per [class.dtor]/1, destructor declaration shall use injected-class-name after ~:

its declarator shall be a function declarator … where … the id-expression has one of the following forms … nested-name-specifier ~class-name and the class-name is the injected-class-name of the class nominated by the nested-name-specifier


P.S. Without preceding ~, the lookup is performed as usual, in the context associated with nested-name-specifier N. So, in the constructor declaration, the second Inner is looked up in the context nominated by Outer::Inner, which is the class scope of struct Inner, finds injected-class-name, and the constructor declaration is valid


Pre-P1787 rule sounded as


in a qualified-id of the form:

nested-name-specifieropt class-name :: ~ class-name

the second class-name is looked up in the same scope as the first


This only means that constructor and destructor can be defined with different scoping rules. The inconsistency is more like a DR, just because std committee is more sane than to have tried such convoluted practice as OP. So although the wording might seem to allow this behavior, the intention of std is most likely not. Hence, we get a DR case.

@Red.Wave P1787 was revisiting, clarifying and even changing lookup rules, but left this rule in place, just reworded it a bit. This seems pretty intentional

What was the argument for it? Why should the constructor declaration be allowed in the same scope that destructor cannot be declared?

@Red.Wave just don't use the preceding Outer::, and you'll be able to declare in the same scope. I haven't looked up for the motivation for the rule, you may try to ask the P1787 author, or post a question on SO
